# How to set ORC BytesColumnVector value to NULL?

Tags: java, orc

I'm writing an ORC file using Groovy.

One of the columns is a String. The ORC column type is:

```
.addField("Name", TypeDescription.createString())
```

The column vector is:

```
BytesColumnVector vName = (BytesColumnVector) batch.cols[1]
```

The values to be assigned to vName may include NULLs, but I can't get ORC to write a null value into its data.

Attempting to assign a null value through set(), setValue() or setRef() throws a null pointer error, either at the point of assignment, or when the batch row is written deeper within ORC.

The closest I can get is this:

```
byte[] b = new byte[0]
vName.setRef (i,b,0,0)
```

but this puts an empty string into the data file, as shown in the following dump snippet (see the second column, 'Name'):

```
{"ProductID":355,"Name":"","MakeFlag":false,"StandardCost":0,"Weight":null,"ModifiedDate":"2014-02-08 10:01:36.827"}
```

Any thoughts on how to set a null string?

**EDIT**: With the answer to this question, I was able to complete some code to write the contents of a database table to ORC. It may be useful to people searching for ORC-related examples.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/orc-adls-polybase-ron-dunn/[enter link description here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/orc-adls-polybase-ron-dunn/)

Comment: An empty string is what I use. But also setting the `vName.isNull[I] = true; vName.noNulls = false;`

Comment: @OmarAli would you please add this as an answer, so that I can upvote it appropriately? You solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An empty string is what I use. I don't think there's another way to do it.

Just make sure you mark the column as containing nulls.

Your code would ideally look like this:

```
BytesColumnVector vName = (BytesColumnVector) batch.cols[1];
byte[] EMPTY_BYTES = "".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
vName.setRef(i, EMPTY_BYTES, 0, 0);
vName.isNull[i] = true;
vName.noNulls = false;
```

Comment: thank for the answer.but the problems is when I read back the string, its not "null" ?